# Why are the addresses not the same?

Tags: c

```
void test(int k);

int main() 
{    
  int i = 0;        
  printf("The address of i is %x\n", &i);
  test(i);
  printf("The address of i is %x\n", &i);    
  test(i);    
  return 0;    
}

void test(int k) 
{    
  print("The address of k is %x\n", &k);    
}
```

Here, `&i` and `&k` addresses are different although `k` holds the value of `i`...

Is this because after function declaration `k` takes separate memory allocation? Please Explain to me!

Comment: in the function you are printing the address of the parameter passed by value, not the address of the variable i.

Comment: To print the address of variable use `%p` format specifier not `%x`. For example `printf("The address of i is %p\n", (void*)&i);`

Comment: This program does not print the same address. You are wrong.

Comment: So if I write your name on two papers, the two papers are both the same sheet because they have your name on them?

Comment: Since you figured it out, consider pressing the green tick to the left on one of the answers below to mark your problem as solved. (Pick the most helpful answer.)

Answer (score 7):

C uses *pass by value*.  This means that function `test` receives a *copy* of the value passed to it.

To see this more clearly, you can look at the values as well as the addresses:

```
int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  printf("The address of i is %p and the value is %d\n", &i, i);
  test(i);
  printf("The address of i is %p and the value is %d\n", &i, i);
  return 0;
}

void test(int k)
{
  printf("The address of k is %p and the value is %d\n", &k, k);
  k = 1;
  printf("The address of k is %p and the value is %d\n", &k, k);
}
```

Here we change the value of `k` in function `test`, but that doesn't change the value of `i` in the caller.  On my machine this prints:

```
The address of i is 0x7ffee60bca48 and the value is 0
The address of k is 0x7ffee60bca2c and the value is 0
The address of k is 0x7ffee60bca2c and the value is 1
The address of i is 0x7ffee60bca48 and the value is 0
```

I've also used `%p`, which is a more portable way to print pointers.

Answer (score 5):

`k` is a copy of `i`.

It's a different variable. If you modify `k`, `i` won't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing by value. so k is copy of i.
if you want to access same i then pass by reference

```
int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  printf("The address of i is %p and the value is %d\n", &i, i);
  test(&i);
  printf("The address of i is %p and the value is %d\n", &i, i);
  return 0;
}

void test(int *k)
{
  *k = 1;
}
```